# ng-class $window.innerWidth

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to find a solution to add a class to an item if the screen width is greater than x (ie. 1200).

```
ng-class="{ large: isLarge() }"

$scope.isLarge = function () {
  return ($window.innerWidth >= 1200);
}
```

This doesn't work, and wont even add the class. It also needs to update on browser resize. Thinking a directive might be a better option.

EDIT: I don't want to hear if this should be done, just if it can be done.

Comment: Why dont you just target it in the css using media query?, that would be the best option

Comment: I would but this is going to effect hundreds of objects that are in sprite sheets. Not something I want to put in a media query since it will add hundreds of lines of css.

Comment: I don't think extra 100s of line in a css file does matter considering the approach you are taking in javascript and that too adding ng-class invoking a function that runs every digest cycle IMHO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *could* do this. I have crafted a directive example which accomplishes this. I chose a width of 500 in this example for an easier JSFiddle demo. Check out the following...

```
<div class="item" resizer></div>
```

---

```
.item {
    background-color: tomato;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.large {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

---

```
app.directive('resizer', ['$window', function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {            
            angular.element($window).on('resize', function () {
                $window.innerWidth > 500 ? 
                    elem.addClass('large') : elem.removeClass('large')
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/45eo8vj0/)

Furthermore, if you wish to leverage a `ng-class` solution, give the following a shot...

```
<div class="item" resizer ng-class="{ 'large': isLarge }"></div>
```

---

```
app.directive('resizer', ['$window', function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {      
            angular.element($window).on('resize', function () {
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.isLarge = $window.innerWidth > 500 ? true : false;
                })
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/s2dna4zs/) - with `ng-class`

Comment: The ng-class version works great, except it doesn't add the class until a resize, even if it should be there on initial load.

Comment: @codephobia thats not a huge issue, just add the same logic at the start of the `link` function. Check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/09yxkdbc/). You might be able to streamline that, but to share the basic idea...

Comment: Yeah it works in the fiddle, but for some reason wont add the class to the element until I cross the "500" threshold and go back.

Comment: I can't think of why that would happen. Can you log out `scope.isLarge` in the `link` function right after the initial window check? This should work. Console errors?

Comment: No errors, console.log returns true, it just isn't applying the class with ng-class... I've seen this issue before, and think maybe it might be a bug in angularjs 1.3. I'll figure it out, but this should get me working. I'll mark this as the correct answer. Thanks!